# Slicing List or String Object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

What is the default range in slicing:
For example:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls[-3::1]  #returns copy of the elements at indexes -3, -2, -1
ls[-3::-1] #returns copy of the elements at indexes -3 till the start of the list i.e ls[-5]
ls[::-1]   #returns copy of the reverse version of the list
ls[::1]    #return the list as is
```

What is the idea behind that? How does python determine unstated start and end indexes?

Comment: If you have a positive step, then the default start is the start and the default end is the end. If you have a negative step then the default start is the end and the default end is the start. The default step is 1.

Comment: It's great that you decided to ask community, but this information you can easily find in official docs. So, what's the point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 1):

If you have a positive step, then the default start is the start and the default end is the end.

If you have a negative step then the default start is the end and the default end is the start.

The default step is 1. The step cannot be zero.

I think that covers all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

For example [a:b:c], so a is start index, b is end index and c means step between indices